# How to write a file remotely using java

Tags: java, file, jsch

I am trying to create a file on a remote server I connected to the server and I am trying now to create the file on the server.

This is my method which connect to the server and going to the write file method which this is the point where I am struggling:

```
public static void writeFileRemotley(Node node,long durationInSec, String data, java.io.File dest) throws Exception {
                if (!dest.exists()) {
                    Credentials credentials = node.findByProtocol(NetworkProtocol.SSH);
                    Shell.builder().
                            setHost(node.ip).
                            setUser(credentials.user).
                            setPassword(credentials.password).
                            setTimeout(durationInSec).build().
                            writeRemoteFile(dest, data);
                }
            }
```

And this is the writeRemoteFile method:

```
public void writeRemoteFile(File file, String data) throws JSchException, IOException {
            ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect(timeoutMilliSec);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(channel.getOutputStream()));

            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
        }
```

I am trying to set the file but did not find a place where I can indicate the server that this is the remote file location.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. I don't think it should be, neither, this would mean a serious security breach. "Let's create a virus-containing file on the server of our ISP, it'll be fun" kind of issues come to mind here.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below method to paste `File` on the Server.

```
channel.put(YOUR_FILE, SFTPLOCATION);
```

Also,
Use `BufferedWriter` to write data in the `File` and once you are done, in `finally` close the file as below.

```
bufferedWriter.flush()
```

Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: thanks for the quick response ,I want to be able to create the file remotely if it does not exist and write data into it.

Comment: So you are now able to create File Sucessfully

Comment: when I use channel.put(file, data) I am getting an error since my first parameter is io.java.File and put first parameter expect to get string variable.
4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/indeni-services/config/environment (No such file or directory)

Comment: Ok I got your point. Do something Like this
1.) Create File Name of String(as:- YOUR_FILE_STREAM)  and then do IO Operation
2.) Once IO operation is Complete
3.) Close the open resource 
4.)Now  Write the below code
File FILENAME = new File(YOUR_FILE_STREAM);

Comment: @prashant what is the file operation u meant?

Comment: File Operation means READ AND WRITE Process of File @tupacshakur

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround to accomplish this task, I used linux commands to create and populate my file like this:

echo "string to insert" > FILE_PATH and I converted it to java command.

Comment: Why do you do this? There are good solutions in the link, I've provided you. Why are you using hacks like this?

Comment: I can use as well code from the links you provided but just for my understanding why the solution I suggested is not good? performance wise? clean code wise?